# How to I scrape data nested within elements using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a URL that's listed under several elements. Specifically, I am trying to pull the word "Everyone" from rating tags, and "No Warnings" from warnings tags.

```
<h3 class="landmark heading">Work Header</h3>

<div class="wrapper">

  <dl class="work meta group" role="complementary">
          <dt class="rating tags">

              Rating:
          </dt>

          <dd class="rating tags">
            <ul class="commas">
               <li><a class="tag" href="/tags/Everyone/works">Everyone</a></li>
            </ul>
          </dd>
          <dt class="warning tags">

              <a href="/tos_faq#tags">Archive Warning</a>:
          </dt>

          <dd class="warning tags">
            <ul class="commas">
               <li><a class="tag" href="/tags/No%20Warnings/works">No Warnings</a></li>
            </ul>
          </dd>
```

I've tried several variations of soup.find() but I keep getting "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'. How can I modify my code to retrieve these items?

```
site = "https://archiveofourown.org/works/44464210?view_full_work=true"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site, headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,features="lxml")

rating = soup.find("dl",{"class":"work meta group"}).find("dd", {"class":"rating tags"}).find("li",{"class":"tag"}).find("a").string
```

Comment: The problem here is you are trying to find a `li` tag with class `tag`. But there is no `li` tag with that class. Change `li` with `a`

Answer (score 0):

##### Verify first

Please check if the `page` that you are receiving from the `urlopen()` call actually contains the html content you are looking for.

##### What you need?

In the html message that you have shared, you are looking to get the `text` part of the html tags, be it under `<dd class="rating tags">` or `<dd class="warning tags">`.

##### How to do it?

If you simply need the textual part of the html tags, then you can try the following and you should get the `text` in a list.

```
>>> import urllib3
>>> import bs4
>>> http = urllib3.PoolManager()
>>> hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
>>> page = http.request('GET', "https://archiveofourown.org/works/44464210?view_full_work=true", headers=hdr)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.data)
```

`page.data` contains the html content to BeautifulSoup to create a parsing tree.

```
>>> rating_tag_elements = soup.find_all('dd', attrs={'class': 'rating tags'})
>>> warning_tag_elements = soup.find_all('dd', attrs={'class': 'warning tags'})
```

These statements are going to give you a list of `bs4.element.Tag` elements.

Now, you can iterate over these lists to get the textual portion under these tags.

```
>>> for element in rating_tag_elements:
        # Do what you want with the text
        print(element.text)
```

You can do the same for warning_tag_elements to extract the text for the warning_tags.

P.S: Thank you [@HedgeHog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14460824/hedgehog) for the reference.

Comment: In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)